Generalizing $P(A)P(B)\ge P(A\cup B)P(A\cap B)$ to $n$ events
Question: Let $E_1,\dots,E_n$ be events in a probability space. Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n{\bf 1}(E_i)$ be the random variable equal to the number of these events which occur. Does this general inequality hold:
$$
P(E_1)P(E_2)\cdots P(E_n)\ge P(X\ge 1)P(X\ge 2)\cdots P(X\ge n)?
$$
Backgorund: For events $A$ and $B$, the general inequality $P(A)P(B)\ge P(A\cup B)P(A\cap B)$ is well-known and easy to prove. Here is one proof. Letting $p_1=P(A\setminus B)$, $p_2=P(B\setminus A)$, and $p_3=P(A\cap B)$, then the inequality to be proved is
$$
(p_1+p_3)(p_2+p_3)\ge (p_1+p_2+p_3)p_3
$$
When you expand both products and subtract, the difference is $p_1p_2$, which is obviously nonnegative.
There is also a version of this inequality for three events. Letting $AB$ denote $A\cap B$, you can prove
$$
P(A)P(B)P(C)\ge P(A\cup B\cup C)\cdot P(AB\cup BC\cup CA)\cdot P(ABC).
$$
There is a proof using a similar method as the two-event case. Let $p_1,\dots,p_7$ denote the probabilities of the disjoint regions of the Venn diagram for the three sets $A, B$ and $C$, where the binary representation of the index determines which sets are included and excluded. For example, since $5$ is $101$ in binary, $p_5$ would be $P(A\cap \overline{B}\cap C)$. Then the inequality to be proved is
$$
\overbrace{(p_1+p_3+p_5+p_7)}^{P(A)}\cdot
\overbrace{(p_2+p_3+p_6+p_7)}^{P(B)}\cdot
\overbrace{(p_4+p_5+p_6+p_7)}^{P(C)} 
\\\ge \\
\underbrace{(p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4+p_5+p_6+p_7)}_{P(A\,\cup \,B\,\cup \,C)}\cdot 
\underbrace{(p_3+p_5+p_6+p_7)}_{P(AB\,\cup \, BC\,\cup \, CA)}\cdot
\underbrace{p_7}_{P(ABC)}
$$
When you expand out the left hand side and the right hand side, you will find that the difference is a polynomial in the seven variables $p_1,\dots,p_7$ whose coefficients are positive integers (WolframAlpha computation). Therefore, the difference is nonnegative.
There is a pattern in these inequalities that generalize to $n$ events, and I was wondering if the general case is also true. Since I cannot think of how to prove it, I ask it as a question.

Note that we can get the 3-event inequality by repeatedly applying the two-event inequality:$$ P(A)P(B)P(C)\\ \ge P(A\cup B)P(A\cap B) P(C) \\\ge P(A\cup B\cup C) P((A\cup B) \cap C) P(A\cap B)\\
= P(A\cup B\cup C) P(BC \cup CA)   P(A B)\\
\ge P(A\cup B\cup C) P(AB \cup BC \cup CA) P(A \cap B\cap C),$$ where $AB = A \cap B$ et c., and the final line uses $(BC \cup CA)\cap AB = B\cap (C\cap A) \cup A \cap (C \cap B) = ABC$.
This makes an inductive proof very natural. You have already shown the base case of $n = 2$, and we assume the inductive hypothesis for $n-1$. Applying this to $\prod_{i \le n-1} P(E_i)$ tells us that
$$ \prod_{1 \le i \le n} P(E_i) \ge P(E_n) \prod_{i = 1}^{n-1} P(X_{n-1} \ge i) ,$$ where $X_{n-1} = \sum_{i \le n-1} 1_{E_i}$. Now, notice that for any $j \in [0:n-1]$, and $X_n = X_{n-1} + 1_{E_n},$
$$ (\{X_{n-1} \ge j\} \cap E_n) \cup \{X_{n-1} \ge j+1\} = \{X_n \ge j+1\}\\ (\{X_{n-1} \ge j\} \cap E_n) \cap \{X_{n-1} \ge j+1\} = \{X_{n-1}\ge j+1\} \cap E_n.$$
This means that, applying the inequality for $n=2,$ we have $$ P(X_{n-1} \ge j , E_n) P(X_{n-1} \ge j+1) \ge P(X_n \ge j+1) P(X_{n-1} \ge j+1, E_n).$$ Finally, notice that $P(E_n) = P(X_{n-1} \ge 0, E_n)$. This means that we can write \begin{align} &\phantom{=} P(E_n) \cdot\prod_{i = 1}^{n-1} P(X_{n-1} \ge i) \\ &= P(X_{n-1} \ge 0, E_n) P(X_{n-1} \ge 1)\cdot \prod_{i = 2}^{n-1} P(X_{n-1} \ge i) \\ &\ge P(X_n \ge 1) P(X_{n-1} \ge 1, E_n) P(X_{n-1} \ge 2) \cdot \prod_{i = 3}^{n-1} P(X_{n-1} \ge i)\\ &\ge \prod_{j = 1}^2 P(X_n \ge j) \cdot P(X_{n-1} \ge 2, E_n) P(X_{n-1} \ge 3)\cdot \prod_{i = 4}^{n-1} P(X_{n-1} \ge i)\\ & \vdots \\ 
&\ge  \prod_{j = 1}^{n-1} P(X_n \ge j) \cdot P(X_{n-1} \ge n-1, E_n) \cdot 1. \end{align} But of course, $X_{n-1} \le n-1,$ so $\{ X_{n-1} \ge n-1 \} \cap E_n = \{X_n \ge n\}$, and we're done.
